# MongoDB NodeJS client connection to Replica Set won't reconnect when the primary goes down

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://mongo1,mongo2,mongo3?replicaSet=rs', {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}, (err, mongoClient) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    mongoClient.db("mydb").collection('mycollection').insertOne({...})
  }, 10000)
})
```

Should MongoClient reconnect to another mongo instance in a replicaSet when the primary goes down and when using the UnifiedTopology? Because in this example **mongoClient** still points to the old primary instance. Is this the intended behavior?

**EDIT**

[Replica Set config](https://gist.github.com/fabio-rizzello-omnia/a367ef4e7557305771940b8dd5669522)

Comment: You can try using the connection string uri format as per the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html). Also, post the configuration of your replica-set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `**mongoose**` as such :

```
if(config.db.indexOf('replicaSet') > - 1) {
  dbOptions = {
    db: {native_parser: true},
    replset: {
      auto_reconnect:false,
      poolSize: 10,
      socketOptions: {
        keepAlive: 1000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000
      }
    },
    server: {
      poolSize: 5,
      socketOptions: {
        keepAlive: 1000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000
      }
    }
  };
}

var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, dbOptions);
```

where

```
config.db =  'mongodb://USER:PW@host1:port1,host2:port2/DBNAME?replicaSet=RSNAME'
```

More elaboration :

The "server" block is only invoked when the connection URI contain a single non clustered connection (aka a single connection string).

The "replset" block is only invoked when the connection URL contains a list of comma separated connection strings (aka replication set).

```
var options = {

    db: {
        native_parser: true
    },

    // This block gets run for a non replica set connection string (eg. localhost with a single DB)
    server: {
        poolSize: 5,
        reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        ssl: false,
        sslValidate: false,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    },

    // This block gets run when the connection string indicates a replica set (comma seperated connections)
    replset: {
        auto_reconnect: false,
        poolSize: 10,
        connectWithNoPrimary: true,
        ssl: true,
        sslValidate: false,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    }
};
```

This block worked on both localhost and the production env.

Comment: What about the configuration for mongodb client without mongoose?

Comment: You can add a shell script to do such as mentioned here [link](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongo-shell-connection)

Comment: I will post a new answer below wish it helps , if it does please upvote it !

Comment: I tried the connection with these options but no success
```
autoReconnect: false,
  poolSize: 10,
  socketOptions: {
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: true
  },
  native_parser: true
```

Comment: did you try the shell script ?

Comment: didn't work either but anyway turns out the actual problem was the replicaset configuration

Answer (score 0):

According to Mongo 3.4 documentation:
In 3.4:

```
mongo "mongodb://host1,host2,host3/myDB?replicaSet=myRS"
```

or

```
mongo "mongodb://host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017/myDB?replicaSet=myRS"
```

Comment: yeah as i wrote in the question the connection string I'm using is just like that.
mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the actual problem was a bad configuration
The 3rd node had priority 0 and votes 0 instead of 1

```json
{
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongo3:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {
                
            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 0
        }
```